# This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature using extended classes

Tags: typescript

I'm not sure if this is a typescript bug or if I am doing something wrong. I'm creating a plugin that generates code. After generation I get the error `This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature` in the generated file.

Minimal reproducable example is underneath. Looks like the error appears when I add *any* variable to any of the extending classes. In this case, if you remove `protected anything = 'test';` the error removes itself.

```js
abstract class GraphtonBaseReturnTypeBuilder {

    public withRelated(relatedType: string, buildFields: (r: GraphtonBaseReturnTypeBuilder) => void): this {
        return this;
    }
}

type UserReturnTypeObjectField = "posts"|"friends";

class UserReturnTypeBuilder extends GraphtonBaseReturnTypeBuilder {
    protected anything = 'test';
    
    public withRelated(relatedType: "posts", buildFields: (r: PostReturnTypeBuilder) => void): this;
    //     ~~~~~~~~~~~ This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature
    public withRelated(relatedType: "friends", buildFields: (r: UserReturnTypeBuilder) => void): this;
    public withRelated(relatedType: UserReturnTypeObjectField, buildFields: (r: GraphtonBaseReturnTypeBuilder) => void): this {
        return super.withRelated(relatedType, buildFields);
    }
}

type PostReturnTypeObjectField = "author"|"repatedPosts";

class PostReturnTypeBuilder extends GraphtonBaseReturnTypeBuilder {

    public withRelated(relatedType: "author", buildFields: (r: UserReturnTypeBuilder) => void): this;
    //     ~~~~~~~~~~~ This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature
    public withRelated(relatedType: "repatedPosts", buildFields: (r: PostReturnTypeBuilder) => void): this;
    public withRelated(relatedType: PostReturnTypeObjectField, buildFields: (r: GraphtonBaseReturnTypeBuilder) => void): this {
        return super.withRelated(relatedType, buildFields);
    }
}
```

The full file is on github: https://github.com/GraphtonLib/Graphton/blob/main/example/graphton.generated.ts

Er erroring lines are [line 229](https://github.com/GraphtonLib/Graphton/blob/main/example/graphton.generated.ts#L229) and [line 259](https://github.com/GraphtonLib/Graphton/blob/main/example/graphton.generated.ts#L259)

Full error:

```
example/graphton.generated.ts:229:12 - error TS2394: This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.

     public withRelated(relatedType: "posts", buildFields: (r: PostReturnTypeBuilder) => void): this;
               ~~~~~~~~~~~

  example/graphton.generated.ts:231:12
    231     public withRelated(relatedType: UserReturnTypeObjectField, buildFields: (r: GraphtonBaseReturnTypeBuilder) => void): this {
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~
    The implementation signature is declared here.

example/graphton.generated.ts:259:12 - error TS2394: This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.

259     public withRelated(relatedType: "author", buildFields: (r: UserReturnTypeBuilder) => void): this;
               ~~~~~~~~~~~

  example/graphton.generated.ts:261:12
    261     public withRelated(relatedType: PostReturnTypeObjectField, buildFields: (r: GraphtonBaseReturnTypeBuilder) => void): this {
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~
    The implementation signature is declared here.
```

Comment: Well, your example was too minimal to be reproducible; generally one should use something like a search approach where you remove code until the error is not reproducible and you add stuff back until it is. [This](https://tsplay.dev/mLL02m) seems to be a [mre] with only a few lines added back in.  This is not a TS bug; TS's type system is structural, so adding and removing fields from a type can change whether it's seen as compatible/incompatible with another type.  The types `interface A {x: string}` and `interface B {x: string}` are the same type because they have the same structure.

Comment: Anyway I suggest [edit]ing the question with a true [mre] and then someone can answer (maybe me, if I have a chance to look at it)

Comment: Ah, another question: you are using generic function types of the form `<T extends Foo>(x: T) => void`.  That is equivalent to the non-generic `(x: Foo) => void` (the compiler will even allow you to assign one to the other).  Since I'd expect you to use `(x: Foo) => void` if you meant that, perhaps you had some other intent for the generic?  A function of the form `<T extends Foo>(x: T) => void` must accept an `x` parameter of any type `T` that the *caller* chooses (as long as `T` is assignable to `Foo`).  If that's not your intent, could you explain what is?

Comment: Well, it kind of looks like you are writing the sort of unsafe subtyping where your overriding method requires something more specific than the overridden method.  This is often useful but not type safe.  TypeScript [allows method parameters to be *bivariant*](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance) to support this, but when you have `--strict` turned on it prevents *function* parameters from being bivariant.

Comment: I think you might want to just [assert](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that your calls are fine and then do [this](https://tsplay.dev/w149AW) instead of using overloads at all.  It's still unsafe and there might be a safe version that uses generics all over the place, but this should at least prevent errors.  If that code meets your needs I can write up an answer; otherwise please elaborate on what use cases are unsatisfied by it.

Comment: @jcalz The file on github I linked is a reproducable example. The whole file is self contained, and has the issue. I'm going to try and remove code until it start working. These types might be simple, but in the end `relatedType` can have more than one string (like "author"|"tags"|"flair") and for each of those strings we get an overloaded method with each their own function. Thanks for all the information in any case!

Comment: Having your reproducible example on an external site is fine as long as it's also included as plaintext in the question (which it currently isn't).  And in any case we're looking for minimal as well as reproducible, so the external file is probably a bit too much.  Do you think [this](https://tsplay.dev/mLL02m) is a good representation of the issue, and if so, could you [edit] the question to include this version?  Or is there some other stuff from the external file which is relevant to the question?

Comment: @jcalz Again thanks - minimal reproducable example is now in the question, including what i need to do to remove the error.

Comment: And does [this](https://tsplay.dev/wg63BW) work for you to fix it?  If not, please edit the example to include enough code so that the unmet need (e.g., other call signatures in the same overload) is demonstrated.

Comment: @jcalz It was a good try, but with the extra overloads (which I have added in the question) this stops working.

Comment: I'd suggest a judicious use of `any` in there like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WyO3ZN); what you are doing is inherently not type safe so you need type assertions and/or `any` to get it to compile.  If you don't want `any` you can write a more cumbersome version like [this](https://tsplay.dev/W4yd1w), but this is not much safer.  If you just want to avoid compiler errors and move on, this is how you should proceed.  Let me know if you'd like an answer to this effect.  If not, please let me know what your unmet needs are.

Comment: And note... if you really do care about type safety, then you probably need to refactor to something more like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NaYnBN) where the superclass does not claim to be able to handle any possible pair of `relatedType` and `buildFields` parameters (since the subclasses can only handle *specific* such pairs).  If you'd prefer to have *this* as an answer, I can write it up instead of the assertion one.

Comment: @jcalz I would prefer that last one as an answer - looks like the perfect solution to my problem since I really do case about typesafety. Like this, I learn a little bit more everyday ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with what you're trying to do is that it's not type safe.  This superclass

```
abstract class GraphtonBaseReturnTypeBuilder {    
    public withRelated(
      relatedType: string, 
      buildFields: (r: GraphtonBaseReturnTypeBuilder) => void
    ): this {
        return this;
    }
}
```

says that a `GraphtonBaseReturnTypeBuilder` has a `withRelated()` method whose first argument is any `string` the caller wants to pass in, and whose second argument is a callback function that must accept any `GraphtonBaseReturnTypeBuilder` the caller wants to pass in.  So, for example, the following must be okay:

```
function process(g: GraphtonBaseReturnTypeBuilder) {
    g.withRelated("randomString", g => console.log(g)); // okay
}
```

And when you declare `class UserReturnTypeBuilder extends GraphtonBaseReturnTypeBuilder`, type safety requires that a `UserReturnTypeBuilder` can do everything a `GraphtonBaseReturnTypeBuilder` can do... and that you can use a `UserReturnTypeBuilder` anywhere a `GraphtonBaseReturnTypeBuilder` is required.  This is known as [substitutability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Meaning the following must also be okay:

```
process(new UserReturnTypeBuilder()); // also okay
```

And so if `UserReturnTypeBuilder` overrides the `withRelated()` method, the only safe way to do it is to accept *at least* the arguments that the method it overrides accepts. If `relatedType` can be any `string` in the superclass, it had better be at least any `string` in the subclass.  It can accept more things (e.g., `string | number` or `unknown`) but it cannot safely accept less (e.g., just `"posts"` or `"friends"`).

---

But the compiler *does* let you be unsafe this way; you are allowed to make `UserReturnTypeBuilder`'s `withRelated` method be incompatible with the same method in `GraphtonBaseReturnTypeBuilder` as long as the incompatibility is a narrowing one.  This is known as [method parameter bivariance](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance) and even though it's unsafe, it's useful enough to be worth allowing:

```
class UserReturnTypeBuilder extends GraphtonBaseReturnTypeBuilder {
  protected anything = 'test';

  public withRelated(
    relatedType: "posts", 
    buildFields: (r: PostReturnTypeBuilder) => void
  ): this;
  public withRelated(
    relatedType: "friends", 
    buildFields: (r: UserReturnTypeBuilder) => void
  ): this;

  public withRelated(
    relatedType: UserReturnTypeObjectField, 
    buildFields: (r: any) => void
  ): this {
      return super.withRelated(relatedType, buildFields);
  }
}
```

But note, when you implement the [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) `withRelated()`, you need to make the implementation signature compatible with the call signatures.  And since the call signatures accept either `(r: PostReturnTypeBuilder) => void` or `(r: UserReturnTypeBuilder) => void`, the implementation must accept those too... something at least as wide as `((r: PostReturnTypeBuilder) => void) | ((r: UserReturnTypeBuilder) => void)`.

But you wrote `(r: GraphtonBaseReturnTypeBuilder) => void)`, and that's not compatible.  If I know that you are giving me a function that accepts a `PostReturnTypeBuilder` or a function that accepts a `UserReturnTypeBuilder`, I can't suddenly assume that function will accept any `GraphtonBaseReturnTypeBuilder` whatsoever.  It's like inviting guests to a party, some of whom can eat fish (`(food: Fish) => void`) and some of whom can eat chicken (`(food: Chicken) => void`) and then deciding to serve beef because "fish and chicken are both food, and so is beef" (`(food: Food) => void`).  That's not how it works (or at least not safely.  Maybe your guests will all be happy with beef, but you don't know that from the above descriptions.)

If you're already going to be unsafe and use bivariant function parameters, then your implementation should probably just annotate `buildFields` as `(r: any) => void`.

But if you do care about type safety, then you will need to refactor your class hierarchy.

---

If you do want safety, then you can't have `GraphtonBaseReturnTypeBuilder` summarily accept `string` for `relatedType` or `(r: GraphtonBaseReturnTypeBuilder) => void` for `buildFields`.  My suggestion here would be to make it [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in some type parameter `RF` corresponding to the related fields for the subclasses, where the keys are the `relatedType` parameter and the values are the corresponding `buildFields` callback argument type:

```
abstract class GraphtonBaseReturnTypeBuilder<RF extends Record<keyof RF, unknown>> {
    public withRelated<K extends keyof RF>(
      relatedType: K, buildFields: (r: RF[K]) => void): this {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Then your subclasses can extend `GraphtonBaseReturnTypeBuilder<RF>` for a particular `RF` tailored to each subclass:

```
interface UserRelatedFields {
    posts: PostReturnTypeBuilder,
    friends: UserReturnTypeBuilder
}
class UserReturnTypeBuilder extends GraphtonBaseReturnTypeBuilder<UserRelatedFields> {

    protected anything = 'test';

    public withRelated<K extends keyof UserRelatedFields>(
      relatedType: K, buildFields: (r: UserRelatedFields[K]) => void) {
        return super.withRelated(relatedType, buildFields); // okay
    }

}

interface PostRelatedFields {
    author: UserReturnTypeBuilder,
    repatedPosts: PostReturnTypeBuilder
}
class PostReturnTypeBuilder extends GraphtonBaseReturnTypeBuilder<PostRelatedFields> {

    public withRelated<K extends keyof PostRelatedFields>(
      relatedType: K, buildFields: (r: PostRelatedFields[K]) => void) {
        return super.withRelated(relatedType, buildFields); // okay
    }
}
```

And this all works because you are never going to have an undifferentiated  `GraphtonBaseReturnTypeBuilder` floating around; it's always going to be a `GraphtonBaseReturnTypeBuilder<UserRelatedFields>` or a `GraphtonBaseReturnTypeBuilder<PostRelatedFields>`, so nothing will accept `"randomString"`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.2#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-loAJAvE7DDhkEKiCRMJTjOLhemSaqUoutKcfq8GIVwyG7qaaixry-Lvu83SkXC05Si6sppoqmbdqSqrFn62p0uWPFuJhdjYWyHIxjW8ZEeBDGTmRyZyW66b1s4rGqQupaaXqUyCsRkmhtBEZxFWZpxKJVqJnIVkyjZrTMR0rhfrm+bzhxzncZWhnVgFt4dI2IzAOMwDkP4tD0ARII0aOkLmT+0kADwiFEfyArcVFiIeGBqJVADWUByLwlwoDV7Jtm1IC8KYIDlJU7QkA5PoJeWlUANJ1ZRrAdV1PU1eUZauT4KBzX5wnGXyVo1QA2nNAC6oWpvKEUTVmMXune4zbrYGCXEgMwfup+0BZFhzHO5ZmeRZ0khC2hpxuJn5AxVhTZcAzyEcG5XivCFENcVaQjpkZXQyjGCVUj9IieNeF6MiqI0hiWIKjipQoPisCUESpOTSp00lrNC1o8CKArd1kNfcTm2eG5O17SJJmE+WImnRdZTOmFkW6Nm0ixZo8Uc-6Lki4o4s1nWKAAPSGygvBtWAch3nDwDPZob3IKZlCCzWkUIUhVpI7jU6gyQOnlvpANO8jU5wwjrDYRBMOo-VPOgljdGR3jlUR5xxPaPebPsZrdjzYt6O851-Mp0TNYbdrFbbbtKX+Rah2B87AWy5dspK77MUwHm6tqZxwsV1Aetpf0Rsm2bFuPcAQA)

Comment: You are a legend. Very clear explanation!

Comment: Using your explaination I've come up with the [following code](https://tsplay.dev/wEGeOm), wich seens te work even without overriding and calling the super method - which is even better! Now I can even refactor more of these. Thanks a million again!